# Run Task when ConEmu is started by running "cmd"

Tags: conemu

I've just started to use ConEmu as a command prompt alternative. I've found something that I believe to be inconsistent that I would like to fix.

If I start ConEmu by double clicking it's icon, then it runs the `{Shells::cmd}` Task which in turn runs `CmdInit.cmd`  out of the ConEmuBaseDir. This changes the prompt of my terminal to one with my username, computer name, current working directory and the actual prompt on a newline beneath it. This is default behavior.

I have gone into the settings and set ConEmu to be my default terminal for console applications.

I have a habit of hitting `Win+R` to open the run window and typing in `cmd` (or just pressing Enter because `cmd` is already there) and it opens the command prompt.

Here's the issue/inconsistency that bugs me. Now with ConEmu, when I go through these steps, the prompt is still the old `cmd.exe` prompt without the colors and the info. What can I do to make sure that ConEmu runs the startup task when ConEmu is run by intercepting the `cmd` command?

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Run `ConEmu.exe`, but not `cmd.exe`.

Why do you think that when you run the application with certain parameters (in your case without parameters at all, just `cmd.exe`) ConEmu may change this concrete command line?

Obviously, if DefTerm is enabled and you run `cmd.exe` you'll get `cmd.exe` in ConEmu tab, if you run `PowerShell.exe`, you'll get `PowerShell.exe` tab, if you run `cmd.exe /k CmdInit.cmd`, you'll get changed prompt.

Nothing wrong, just simple logic.

Comment: It's a command prompt replacement. 99% of the rest of my terminal interactions so far are replaced by ConEmu automatically. Why not this too?

Comment: It's **terminal** replacement! `cmd.exe` is **not** a terminal, it's console application! https://conemu.github.io/en/Delusions.html#delusion-2

Comment: Splitting those hairs is not an answer to my question. Nor is trying to invalidate the question. Running a task when a certain process is started in ConEmu doesn't sound unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"AutoRun"="\"c:\\Program Files\\ConEmu\\ConEmu\\CmdInit.cmd\" \"/GHWND=NEW\""
```